# How to display header Component only on certain pages in Angular (now it diplays only on reload)

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-components, angular-component-router

I have an app that has a HomeComponent, where I don't want to show a HeaderComponent.
Also, I have other 4 routes where I do want to render the Header.
I could made it work, but there is a little bug when I navigate from HomeComponent, to any other component. It doesn't render the HeaderComponent, but when I reload the page on the navigator, it show the header correctly.
I tried a lot of things and can't make it work properly yet...

**What i want**
Show HeaderComponent on all routes, except for /home (HomeComponent).

***Here is my code***
app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { ContactoComponent } from './contacto/contacto.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { PortfolioComponent } from './portfolio/portfolio.component';
import { SkillsComponent } from './skills/skills.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent, data: { animation: 'fader' } },
  {
    path: 'contacto',
    component: ContactoComponent,
    data: { animation: 'fader' },
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

app-module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { CvComponent } from './cv/cv.component';
import { ContactoComponent } from './contacto/contacto.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    ContactoComponent,
    CvComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgbModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.component.html

```
<app-header *ngIf="router.url !== '/home'"></app-header>
<router-outlet> </router-outlet>
```

I also tried to call `<app-header></app-header>` on top of each template 'about.component.html' and 'contacto.component.html' but I had the same results...

I guess that is trying to show HeaderComponent, but it is not exist until I reload the page. Please can you please help me....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a layout component and load your other pages as child route inside layout component and put header inside layout component .

```
const routes: Routes = [
{path:'home':component : homecomponent}
{
 path: ' ',
 component: HeaderOnlyLayoutComponent,
 children: [
  { path: 'youotherpath', component: 
   childcomponent },
  ]
  }
]
```

You can see full description and example here
[Link](https://indepth.dev/posts/1235/how-to-reuse-common-layouts-in-angular-using-router-2)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Now I can show the homepage without the header. The link has very useful example. Thank you very much! (:

Answer (score 0):

From my observation, you have faded the header out but never faded it back in except when loading.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).